# Map Range of Numbers to 0 through 100

Tags: php, algorithm, math

I have a possibility of numbers between +/- 6 including 0 (ie. 6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6) that come out of a ranking algorithm I have in PHP.

Instead of returning +/- 6, I would like to return a number between 0 to 100. The correlation would be similar to:

100 = +6  
..  
75 = +3  
..  
50 = 0  
..  
25 = -3  
..  
0 = -6

Considering the output range of the ranking algorithm, how would I programmatically achieve this in PHP? I've considered the following but am unsure as to the best approach:

```
function score_alg($x) {
  if ($x == '6')
    return 100;
  if ($x == '3')
    return 75;
  if ($x == '0')
    return 50;
  if ($x == '-3')
    return 25;
  if ($x == '-6')
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add 6, multiply by 100, and divide by 12?

Comment: or use `array('6'=> '100', '3' => '75', ..)` then return `$array[$x]` if there is no linear equation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would work:

```
function score_alg($x) {
  return round(($x+6)*(100/12));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One more variation:

```
// Converts a range of numbers to a percentage scale
// $n       number to convert
// $lRange  lowest number of the range  [-6 default]
// $hRange  highest number in the range [6 default]
// $scale   percentage scale            [100 default]
function toPct($n, $lRange = -6, $hRange = 6, $scale = 100){
  // reversed high and low
  if ($lRange > $hRange){
    $lRange = $lRange + $hRange;
    $hRange = $lRange - $hRange;
    $lRange = $lRange - $hRange;
  }

  // input validation
  if ($n < $lRange || $n > $hRange) {
    trigger_error('$n does not fall within the supplied range', E_USER_ERROR);
    return FALSE;
  }

  // edge cases
  if ($n == $lRange) return 0;
  if ($n == $hRange) return $scale;

  // everything in between
  $range = $hRange - $lRange;
  if ($lRange < 0){
    $n += abs($lRange);
  }
  return ($n / $range) * $scale;
}
```

Demonstration:

```
$lRange = -6; $hRange = 6;
for ($i = $lRange; $i <= $hRange; $i++){
  echo $i . ' = ' . toPct($i, $lRange, $hRange) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
-6 = 0
-5 = 8.3333333333333
-4 = 16.666666666667
-3 = 25
-2 = 33.333333333333
-1 = 41.666666666667
0  = 50
1  = 58.333333333333
2  = 66.666666666667
3  = 75
4  = 83.333333333333
5  = 91.666666666667
6  = 100
```

Comment: A bit overkill, but this would be helpful for other people with similar problems

Comment: @StephenTG: Agreed, overkill. However, it is flexible and I try to keep the answers as "generic" as possible (for future googlers) while also solving the OPs problem at-hand.

Comment: That's an admirable philosophy

Comment: I just tried using this function, and I'm getting values come through as 300%, despite them being smaller then the highest value, and the scale is set to 100.

Comment: Just checked, seems to be flawed. try `toPct(50, 0, 999)` and you'll get a value of 105.00500500501, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: @mrpablo sounds like a rounding issue, ill take a look.

Comment: @MrPablo Should be good now (50 out of 999 is ~5%, so 5.005 is returned now).

Comment: Much better, but not as concise as my solution ;)

Comment: @MrPablo I'm not here to win contests, just help others. It's up to the end beneficiary which solution they go with, I can only offer another option. I also opted to explain the solution over providing a one liner (which is, imho, more if the spirit of SO-- helping others).

Answer (score 1):

You can "stretch" out the ranges:

```
function score_alg($x) {
    return round(($x + 6) * (100 / 12));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd do something like this:

```
function score_alg($x) {
  $val = ($x + 6)*(100/12); 
  return round($val);
}
```

**Output:**

```
echo score_alg(6); //100
echo score_alg(3); //75
echo score_alg(0); //50
echo score_alg(-3); //25
echo score_alg(-6); //0
```

Comment: I think you mean `(100/12)`

Comment: @WillemEllis: shouldn't it be 13? including the 0?

Comment: No, your range is from -6 to 6, which equals 12

Comment: (0 + 6)*(100/13) != 50

Comment: And `(6 + 6) * (100 / 13) != 100`

Comment: Yeah, sorry that's simply not true. As an electrical engineer who has had to do several A/D conversions, it's definitely `MAX - MIN = 6 - -6 = 6 + 6 = 12`

Comment: Lol. Do the math.  12*(100/13)=~92

Comment: @TimWithers: indeed. Updated. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a small general range function I utilise:

```
function mapToRange($value, $in_min, $in_max, $out_min, $out_max ) {
   return round(($value - $in_min) * ($out_max - $out_min) / ($in_max - $in_min) + $out_min);
}
```

Use as follows:

`echo ( mapToRange( 0, -6, 6, 0, 100 )); // output is 50`

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
function score_alg($x) {
  return round(($x + 6)*(100/12)); 
}
```

Comment: @WillemEllis Guessed as much. So why the downvotes, mystery people?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but -- without rounding, the answer would always be a float, therefore Tim's answer was the first *correct* answer.

Comment: Since your answer is the same answer as TimWithers' you should deleted yours.

Comment: @LucM There are three identical answers on this question. Mine came up first, but Tim's was the first to have rounding.

Answer (score 0):

Most answers here are dealing with your specific case, with only one solution covering any case, however, it is incorrect.

Below is a quicker solution, that should work across the board.

```
/*
* $value // the value
* $min // minimum value of the range
* $max // maximum value of the range
*/
function toPercentage($value, $min, $max) {
  return ($value - $min) / ($max - $min) * 100;
};
```